# Translate Algebraic expressions into programming

Tags: javascript

I am looking at algebra and trying to find methods to translate expressions into programming loops.

[image]

The simple version of this center of gravity equation (as I understand) would be to find a **single** value from a data set.

sudo code:

```
var Price=[];//Array of imaginary numbers

var i=Price.length;

var S1     = 0.0,
    S2     = 0.0,
    Answer = 0.0;

while(i--){

   S1 += (i+1) * Price[i];

   S2 += Price[i];

   if(!i){Answer = S2/S1;}
   }
```

In the expression *Σ* (Sigma) is the instruction to sum up where *N* would be the number of times and *i* is the iteration.

Why is the *i* in (i+1) shown as an *x* in the expression?

Comment: Forgive my curiosity, but what sort of Centre-of-Gravity calculation involves adding up a set of Prices?

Comment: It's not an *x*, it's *x_i*. There are two inputs to this function: a list of items (The x's) and a list of weights (which in the function are called Prices)